# Squid Proxy - Authentication if someone invokes a block via SquidGuard?

Tags: active-directory, proxy, ldap, squid

I'm configuring a Linux proxy with Squid and SquidGuard to filter Internet traffic.

I know how to authenticate users against Active Directory (using the basic auth helper) in Squid, and then how to filter access for users using SquidGuard.

In my currently running config, the user gets prompted for his username/password every time he closes and opens the browser.

The question: how can I ask for username/password if the user calls up a "bad" url? (URL on Blacklist of SquidGuard)

My goal is to be able to ask for username/password only if someones calls up a URL on the Blacklists.

I know SquidGuard is rather restricted in terms of configuration for authentication. But I couldn't find any config examples or help concerning my  aim. Of course I'm open for workarounds or entirely different configurations, the result should be the similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usual proxy authentication cannot be used in this case. The goal of proxy authentication is to authenticate request(response); by the time your SquidGuard (SG) blocked a request/response this has already been delivered from the server to your Squid.

What you seem to be requesting is the "bypass blocked URL" functionality - for example, SquidGuards blocks access to a "bad" URL and the "blocked" page gets presented to the user. He will then be able to click on the blocked page and provide bypass password - next request for the "bad" URL will not be blocked by SG.

If this is so then as far as I know it is not possible to do in SG. Try looking at DansGuardian.

Comment: It will be in 5.1 of https://www.diladele.com BTW